# I am manually bootstrapping angular. Even though the module is injected it's having trouble loading

Tags: angularjs

Here i am declaring a module.

```
angular.module('users', []);
```

Here i am bootstrapping.

```
var mainApplicationModuleName = 'mean';

var mainApplicationModule = angular.module(mainApplicationModuleName, ['ngRoute', 'users']);

mainApplicationModule.config(['$locationProvider',
 function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
   }
]);

if (window.location.hash === '#_=_') window.location.hash = '#!';

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, [mainApplicationModuleName]);
});
```

i have declared all the scripts in the html file, but it still having trouble loading.

Comment: what are the errors you have in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that your script files are refered in correct order as below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/application.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/users/users.client.module.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/core/core.client.module.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/core/controllers/core.client.controller.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/core/config/core.client.routes.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/users/services/authentication.client.service.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/articles/articles.client.module.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/articles/controllers/articles.client.controller.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/articles/services/articles.client.service.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/articles/config/articles.client.routes.js"></script>
```

Second in your users.server.controller.js file modify the method.

```
User.findById({
        id: id             /// modified here
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
        } else {
            req.user = user;
            next();
        }
    });
```